# Unknown angle in an isosceles triangle with inscribed triangles having angles 20°,30°,50°,60°

Tags: geometry

I'm posed with the following question:

[image]

I've attempted to deconstruct it:

[image]

Throw me a bone or give me a clue as to how I may solve it.

Comment: Oh, this thing again! :-)  It's an old chestnut.  It's often found online as the World's Hardest Geometry Problem, or something like that.  It isn't that, quite, but it is pretty challenging.  If you want to know the answer, you can probably google it from that.  I'm not sure what a good hint is that doesn't give the whole thing away.  Maybe: Look for a construction line that yields useful isosceles triangles...

Comment: Looking at your diagram, you've made a good start.  However your presentation leaves us Readers guessing what methods are allowed for the problem.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title which did not reflect the content of the question : this can be useful for subsequent requests